# Python selenoid: бесконечное выполнение цикла

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Суть в чем: у меня есть образ ВМ Linux Ubuntu 18.04, в нем я запускаю небольшой python скрипт, который при помощи selenoid открывает определенную страницу в браузере и запускает js код. Далее этот код должен выполняться **бесконечное** количество времени. Однако примерно спустя 1 минуту скрипт вылетает с ошибкой: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Session timed out or not found`. Стоит отметить, что когда я запускаю этот код просто используя selenium на своем компьютере под windows - все работает четко. Как я понял, мне нужно что-то сделать с sessionTimeout, но я никак не могу понять что и как заставить мой код работать бесконечно долго.

Answer (score 2):

Это значит у вас в тестах есть шаги, которые не отправляют запросов в `selenium` больше 1 минуты. Либо найдите и ускорьте такие шаги, либо увеличьте таймаут через капабилити `sessionTimeout = n` ,`n` - необходимое время работы цикла